# float input / Python

Tags: python

The problem is that, I can't input square brackets before my numbers in list.

```
(ValueError: could not convert string to float: '[')
```

The code is :

```
list1 = [float(a) for a in input().split(', ')]
str_lst = sorted(list1, reverse=True)[:3]
print(*str_lst, sep=" ")
```

And the task is to write float numbers, for example, [29.0, 23.3, 45.0, 4.3, 12.4, 34.5] and print only 3 max in descending sequence, like, 45.0 34.5 29.0 or [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0] and print only 0.0 0.0 0.0.

When I write numbers without [] then its allright, but it didn't work with [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0].

What should I do to get these brackets and to make it work also with [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]?

Thank You, I appreciate it!

Comment: It does not work, because `[0` is not a valid argument to `float` call. You might need a `literal_eval` in that case.

Comment: Is this `[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]` a list embedded in a string?

Comment: why do you want to enter brackets?

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using the json library for something like this.

For example:

```
json.loads('[29.0, 23.3, 45.0, 4.3, 12.4, 34.5]')
```

Ouputs:

```
[29.0, 23.3, 45.0, 4.3, 12.4, 34.5]
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot convert `[0` to a float value. The issue here is you are reading the input list as a string value and then manipulating with string while you can convert the list embedded in string using `ast.literal_eval`

```
import ast
list1 = [float(a) for a in ast.literal_eval(input())]
```

While one should avoid using `ast` as far as possible. Another way could be just string manipulation and replacing the `[` and `]` from string

```
import re
re.sub('[\[|\]]','','[29.0, 23.3, 45.0, 4.3, 12.4, 34.5]')
```